# ngSubmit no funciona, pero is pongo onsubmit si

Tags: angular

component.html

```
<div class="auth-wrapper">
<form class="form-signin"   [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser()" >
    <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center">Please sign up</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { AuthService } from './../../shared/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  signupForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ) {
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      email: [''],
      mobile: [''],
      password: ['']
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  registerUser() {
    this.authService.signUp(this.signupForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.result) {
        this.signupForm.reset()
        this.router.navigate(['log-in']);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

En component.html, si cambio el ngSubmit por onsubmit y le pongo por ejemplo un alert('hola'), funciona, en cambio si pongo el alert con el ngSubmit, no hace nada, por lo tanto tampoco está haciendo el registerUser, he puesto alert en la función registerUser y tampoco lo hace, no está haciendo la función en absoluto

Answer (score 0):

//prueba de la siguiente manera

```
 <div class="auth-wrapper">
   <form class="form-signin" #e="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(e)" >
<h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center">Please sign up</h3>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Sign up</button>
```

Comment: ahora me da este error: core.js:3864 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Export of name 'ngForm' not found!
Error: Export of name 'ngForm' not found!

Comment: debes trael elmodulo del core de angular en tu metodo registerUser(){} `registerUser(e: NgForm){}` `import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: esta usando reactive forms no template forms

Comment: claro, estoy usando reactive forms amigo

Comment: no le había prestado atención al `subscribe` perdón, de esta menera retiro lo dicho ya que descubrí Rxjs hace no mas de 3 días y no tengo conocimiento para aportar, espero que encuentres solución, disculpa